# How do you block video auto-play for a specific URL?

Tags: brave, brave-browser

I know you can block an address by adding it to `brave://settings/content/autoplay`. However, I'm trying to block *only* the root address of a site, rather than its entirety.

I want to block:

```
https://www.example.com
```

But I don't want to block:

```
https://www.example.com/other/page
https://www.example.com/another/page
https://www.example.com/yet/another/page
https://www.example.com/this/other/page
```

The other pages aren't necessarily known (they're generated by whatever content is being posted), so I cannot individually add them to an allowlist.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a dollar sign to the end to signal the end of the line.

```
https://www.example.com$
```

Though I'm not sure if that settings page can accept that kind of regex. Worth a try.